# Not printing background in knitr so watermark is visible

Tags: r, knitr

How to have background for R chunk in knitr not printed so that Watermark is shown. Minimal example:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{draftwatermark}
 \SetWatermarkText{Watermark}
 \SetWatermarkScale{5}
 \begin{document}
 Some code that takes up a few inches of space.
 <<background=c(1,1,1)>>=
 x <- matrix(c(10,20,30,40),nrow=2)
 chisq.test(x)
 chisq.test(x)
 chisq.test(x)
 @
 \end{document}
```

The watermark prints behind the background. In order for the watermark to show I want to have no background. Is this possible?